# Space which is path connected but not locally path connected

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, path-connected, locally-connected

Can you give an example of a topological space which is path connected but not locally path connected, besides the graph of $\sin(1/x)$?

Comment: Note that the "topologist's sine curve" is *not* path-connected in its standard form. It's connected but not locally connected.

Answer (score 2):

An example is the [comb space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space),

which is $(\{0\}\times[0,1])\cup(K\times[0,1])\cup([0,1]\times\{0\}),$ where $K=\{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$,

with the subspace topology in $\mathbb R^2$.